# Undefined offset in PHP Class - wikipedia

Tags: php

I am new to PHP - I keep getting an undefined offset in my php class.

Can anyone help please - my code is below. Current error is on line 28 but there may be more.

The Error Displayed is:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wikipedia.class.php on line 28

This class enables me to parse wikipedia content and display it in php - any ideas what the undefined offset may be.

```
<?PHP
class wikipedia
{
public function __construct($wiki)
    {
    $this->wiki = $wiki;
    }
public function __destruct()
    {
    unset($this->wiki);
    }
public function get_page($name, $header = false)
    {
    $file = file_get_contents($this->wiki.'/wiki/'.$name);
    $file = str_replace('href="/', 'href="'.$this->wiki.'/', $file);
    //$file = str_replace('href="#', 'href="'.$this->wiki.'/wiki/'.$name.'#',      $file);
    preg_match_all('#<!-- start content -->(.*?)<!-- end content -->#es',  $file, $ar);
    unset($file);
    IF(is_array($ar[1]))
        {
        IF($header == false)
            {
            return $ar[1][0];
            }
        else
            {
            return '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl" dir="ltr"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$this->wiki.'/skins-1.5/monobook/main.css" /></head><body>'.$ar[1][0];
            }
        }
    else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
public function edit_page($name, $header = false)
    {
    $file = file_get_contents($this->wiki.'/w/index.php?  title='.$name.'&action=edit');
    preg_match_all('#<textarea (.*?)ols=\'80\' >(.*?)</textarea>#es', $file,  $ar);
    unset($file);
    IF(is_array($ar[2]))
        {
        ob_start();
        IF($header != false)
            {
            echo '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xml:lang="pl" lang="pl" dir="ltr"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$this- >wiki.'/skins-1.5/monobook/main.css" /></head><body>';
            }

        $xname = 'wpTextbox1';
        echo '<Form action="'.$this->wiki.'/w/index.php? title='.$name.'&amp;action=submit" METHOD="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="rk"  id="editform"><center>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function emoticon('.$xname.') {
            '.$xname.' = \'\' + '.$xname.' + \'\';
            if (document.rk.'.$xname.'.create'.$xname.'Range &&  document.rk.'.$xname.'.caretPos) {
            var caretPos = document.rk.'.$xname.'.caretPos;
            caretPos.'.$xname.' =  caretPos.'.$xname.'.charAt(caretPos.'.$xname.'.length - 1) == \' \' ? '.$xname.' + \' \' :  '.$xname.';
            document.rk.'.$xname.'.focus();
            } else {
            document.rk.'.$xname.'.value  += '.$xname.';
            document.rk.'.$xname.'.focus();
            }
            }
            </script>';

            echo '<center><textarea cols="75" rows="30" name="'.$xname.'">'.$ar[2][0].'</textarea><BR>
            <input type="button" value="Link to a wiki page" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'[[wiki_page]]\')">
            <input type="button" value="Link" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'[http://your_url.pl Page Title]\')">
            <input type="button" value="Graphic" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'[[Grafika:filename]]\')">
            <input type="button" value="H1 - Big Title" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'= Title =\')">
            <input type="button" value="H2 - Medium Title" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'== Title ==\')">
            <input type="button" value="H3 - Small Title" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'=== Title ===\')">
            <input type="button" value="LI - lists" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'* Text here\')">
            <input type="button" value="LI - numeric lists" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'# Text here\')">
            <input type="button" value="Definition" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'; Definition name : Description\')">
            <input type="button" value="HR - line" onClick="javascript:emoticon(\'----\')"><BR><BR>';

        echo '<BR><input tabindex=\'5\' id=\'wpSave\' type=\'submit\' value="Save" name="wpSave" accesskey="s">
        <input tabindex=\'6\' id=\'wpPreview\' type=\'submit\'  value="Preview" name="wpPreview" accesskey="p">
        <input tabindex=\'7\' id=\'wpDiff\' type=\'submit\' value="Preview Changes" name="wpDiff" accesskey="v"></center></form>';
        $wynik = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $wynik;
        }
    else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\wikipedia.class.php on line 28

Answer (score 1):

Maybe change

```
IF(is_array($ar[1]))
```

to

```
IF(is_array($ar[1]) && isset($ar[1][0]))
```

Comment: can anyone correct the code that I have placed in the box above - not exactly sure what should be chanegd as there are many different answers.

Comment: none of the answer is different, at the end everyone is concluding the same, that the array element $ar[1][0] doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You are using `preg_match_all()` to do some regex and to put the matches in `$ar`.

Try doing a `var_dump($ar)` to see what the array looks like. Most likely, you did not have any matches, so the element `$ar[1][0]` is empty.

If the array element can sometimes be empty, check with `isset()` first before doing further operations on it.

Comment: can anyone correct the code that I have placed in the box above - not exactly sure what should be chanegd as there are many different answers.

Comment: none of the answer is different, at the end everyone is concluding the same, that the array element $ar[1][0] doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that no match was found, thus the array is empty and there is no index 0. You could add a check, and return boolean false if not found, use the function `isset()` for this

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex is returning no matches, hence you are trying to return an array element that does not exist.